$\int_{|z| = 1} e^\frac{1}{z^2}dz$?
I'm having a tough time figuring out the integral $\int_{|z| = 1}e^\frac{1}{z^2}dz$. My first reaction was to find the series of the function so that I could find residues, but then discovered that $e^\frac{1}{z^2} = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{z^{2n}n!}$, so there isn't a nice $-1$st power term to locate the residue at. I'm now a bit stumped at how to proceed. Cauchy's integral formula doesn't seem helpful and it doesn't seem possible to calculate it directly with paramaterizing the circle in terms of $t$. Could I have some guidance on how to proceed? Thanks for your time.

There is a $z^{-1}$ term, it just has a coefficient of zero.

facepalm Thank you Ian!

Since the function has $f(z)=f(-z),$ and $f$ is analytic in the domain, the integral is $0.$

Following the idea of power series expansion, you can interchange summation and integration to get that you have $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \oint \frac{z^{-2n}}{n!} dz$, and all the terms are zero since the path is closed and there is no $z^{-1}$ term, so the sum is zero.
